# Separating a string using a regex pattern

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to get multiple variables from a single regex match.

```
std::string string_to_search = "abc def ghi";
std::regex pattern = "abc (.+) (.+)";
regex_search(string_to_search);
std::string segment1 = //assign to first [a-z]*
std::string segment2 = //assign to second [a-z]*
```

In ruby what I am trying to do is

```
case string_to_search

    when /\Aabc (.+) (.+)/
        segment1 = $1
        segment2 = $2
end
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I don't know how to separate the string into separate variables based on the pattern.

Comment: Have you examined the functions exposed in `<regex>` and tried calling one with valid parameters, you know, to start?

Comment: I was looking at regex_iterator, but that would require me to create multiple regexes(regi?) which I guess I could do, but I was hoping wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two groups can be obtained as follows:

```
std::string string_to_search = "abc def ghi";
std::regex pattern ("abc (.+) (.+)");
std::smatch base_match;


if (std::regex_match(string_to_search, base_match, pattern))
{
    std::cout << base_match[1] << endl; // def
    std::cout << base_match[2] << endl; // ghi
}
```

Description of regex_match and how to use it is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match).